# Payment via User card id using Stripe PHP API?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am using stripe php api. When payment succeed information using `$Card and $customer` object store in database e.g card id , card brand etc.website have page where all user card number show in form of `***4242`. Now when user pay for something next time, user select the card which is last4 digit `***4242` from his card record and payment will done using Card ID `card_1BLoXK2eZvKYlo2CUZoDPXh1`. is it possible pay using customer card Id and big question how can i manage that using stripe checkout modal box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Stripe Checkout is for tokenizing cards, not managing cards that have already been tokenized and attached to customers.  You'll need to build some kind of user interface to do this.

You can, however, charge these cards simply by using the Create a Charge API endpoint detailed below:

https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge

Simply provide a `customer` and `source` argument equal to the Customer ID and the Card ID respectively.

Hope that helps!